# Couchbase iOS:How to convert a CBLDocument to NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, loops, properties, document, couchbase

What I am trying to do is convert a document to an dictionary and then iterate that dictionary to see what's inside, but I am having the following problem when trying to convert the document.
I have the following code:

```
CBLDocument *document = row.value;
NSDictionary *dict = document.properties;
```

the xCode is always complaining "[__NSCFDictionary currentRevision]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x90c4150" when running to the second statement.
I have also tried NSDictionary *dict = document.currentRevision.properties;
It's not working either.
Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out row.value is not a document(is actually a dictionary), but nobody tells me that when I emit(@[somekey], doc); The doc (which is the value) is actually a dictionary instead of a document. 
But weird though the compiler did not complain when assigning the dictionary to a CBLDocument.